# Scalarize a function in R for dplyr's mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to compute the two-proportion test over four individuals in R.

```
> example <- data.frame(x = 41:44, y = 43:46, z = c(100,100,100,100), w = c(101,101,101,101))
> example
   x  y   z   w
1 41 43 100 101
2 42 44 100 101
3 43 45 100 101
4 44 46 100 101
```

Specifically, I would want the p-value from the `prop.test` function

```
> prop.test(c(41,43), c(100,101))$p.value
[1] 0.9336564
```

added to each row. I would like to continue using the `mutate` function from `dplyr`, which lets me do things like this easily:

```
> example %>% mutate(total = x + y + z + w)
   x  y   z   w total
1 41 43 100 101   285
2 42 44 100 101   287
3 43 45 100 101   289
4 44 46 100 101   291
```

However, this doesn't do what I expected for vectorized functions, like `sum()`.

```
> example %>% mutate(total = sum(x,y,z,w))
   x  y   z   w total
1 41 43 100 101  1152
2 42 44 100 101  1152
3 43 45 100 101  1152
4 44 46 100 101  1152
> example %>% mutate(just_z = sum(z))
   x  y   z   w just_z
1 41 43 100 101    400
2 42 44 100 101    400
3 43 45 100 101    400
4 44 46 100 101    400
```

As shown, the vectorized `sum()` function takes the entire column `z` instead of reading only the value of `z` on the appropriate row. As a result, the `prop.test` I was trying to run gives an unexpected result:

```
> example %>% mutate(p = prop.test(c(x,y), c(z,w))$p.value)
   x  y   z   w         p
1 41 43 100 101 0.9989672
2 42 44 100 101 0.9989672
3 43 45 100 101 0.9989672
4 44 46 100 101 0.9989672
```

I can get to my answer with some hideous procedural programming or list comprehension:

```
> to_vec(for(i in 1:length(example))
+     prop.test(c(example$x[i], example$y[i]),
+               c(example$z[i], example$w[i]))$p.value)
[1] 0.9336564 0.9349922 0.9362936 0.9375628
```

but this approach is inelegant. Is there a way to "scalarize" a vectorized function or otherwise for `mutate` to operate only on row members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such operations you can use `rowwise` :

```
library(dplyr)
example %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(p = prop.test(c(x,y), c(z,w))$p.value)

#      x     y     z     w     p
#  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    41    43   100   101 0.934
#2    42    44   100   101 0.935
#3    43    45   100   101 0.936
#4    44    46   100   101 0.938
```

Or `pmap` variants from `purrr`.

```
example %>% mutate(p = purrr::pmap_dbl(., 
               ~{x <- c(...);prop.test(x[1:2], x[3:4])$p.value}))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easier with `apply` from `base R` and these row wise functions have not much significant difference in efficiency by loading external packages

```
apply(example, 1, function(x) prop.test(x[1:2], x[3:4])$p.value)
#[1] 0.9336564 0.9349922 0.9362936 0.9375628
```